# Renault Logan 2011 unknown electrical issue

Tags: automatic-transmission, electronics, gears, renault

I have a Renault Logan 2011 since March 2018 and it has run for about 173,000 km so far.

About a year back it started having this strange problem where during initial start the automatic transmission would not change the gear properly and the 'electronic error' indicator on the dashboard would light up, the transmission would be stuck in 2nd gear and making strange sound and the engine RPM would go high because there were no change in gear.

The mechanic advised that the gear box must be replaced. I didn't go for that because I Googled about the issue and the advise was that it could most likely be due to the electronic system because the system manages the transmission (gear changes) so it might not be a problem with the gear box itself.

It got even stranger when in the winter the car had this issue more often than in the summer! in winter even when the gear transmission is working properly the 'electronic error' indicator lights up and the engine would go through higher RPM than usual before next gear change.

Also, in winter I cannot drive in one speed straight for more than 5 seconds otherwise the transmission runs into the same problem with a big jolt. It is difficult on highways, where then I have to change speeds constantly.
When the car runs into this problem I have to pull over turn off the engine and turn it on again.

Now I am thinking about taking the car to a computerized check-up center but I don't know if they will be able to find out exactly what is causing the issue?

Comment: Please edit with some paragraphs - a wall of text is challenging to read.

Comment: Since you have an "electronic error" message light up, that means that the car is aware of this problem.  Get a code reader to see what the exact problem is.  When diagnosing electric problems, those things are immensely helpful.  Moreover, if you have the service manual, then it would actually tell you which things might be the cause of a given error code.

Comment: Find the fault codes. My previous (not Renault) auto box failed and the diagnosis was the "mechatronic" unit. The main dealer however wanted to replace the entire  gearbox. Which would have been an unnecessary expense of about 4x the cost of the actual refurb needed.